# How to delete a parameter inside an object?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've take a look for some answers about this but any worked here.

I have this object:

```
[ { transactionId: 'oapcfgajnasdasddmamdgogjilkjga.AO-J1Oyho4K_fgrzggggggasdasdasdykGfBYG4',
    orderId: undefined,
    productId: 'casdasd',
    purchaseDate: 1asd4831asdasd2080asd5241,
    quantity: 1,
    expirationDate: '14asdggg8g1' } ]
```

I need to delete the orderId parameter.
I tried this two options of code but did not work.

one:

```
 var index = productsList.indexOf("orderId");
        productsList.splice(index, 1);
```

two:

```
           for(var i=0 ; i<productsList.length; i++)
{
    if(productsList[i].value=='orderId')
        productsList.splice(i);
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: delete object.property

Comment: the difference here I think is the [  ] characters... do you know how to avoid them? @DontVoteMeDown, Musa

Comment: delete productsList[0].orderId

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Using [delete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) operator:

```
delete yourObject.orderId
```

Comment: it would be delete productList.orderId right? let me test

Comment: @arnoldssss Exactly, it will remove the property from productList object

Comment: Hi andres.. I think that did not work... the parameter still has that value

Comment: I think that is because of this []

Comment: First you need to find your object in the array. Assuming that your object is in the position 0 of the array and productList your object: `var productsList = productsListArray[0]; delete productsList.orderId`